# Javascript hex string fromCharCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, hex

Hex string:

```
var str = [0x6A, 0xE8, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xD9, 0xDC, 0x0A, 0x09];
byte = '';
for (var i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
    byte += String.fromCharCode( parseInt(str[i], 16).toString(16) );
}
```

But receiver show:

```
6A C3A8 05 01 00 01 C399 C39C 0A 09
```

Any idea how to keep it 2 bytes? Or maybe my code wrong, esp. for nodejs?

*Updated the script.
I'm kinda new with nodejs and I like to see what non-blocking events nodejs' offer because in "busy" day I have some missing data.
Got the script working for python using binascii.(un)hexlify and PHP mbstring (un)pack (for web view).

Expecting:

```
6A E8 05 01 00 01 D9 DC 0A 09
```

Comment: Why do you need: "String.fromCharCode"
If you're already using: ".toString(16)"
then you've already got a String .

Comment: 1) Try typing `0x6a` in node interpreter and see what happens, note how it differs from `"0x6a"`. 2) Argument for `String.fromCharCode` is super strange. 3) Also, don't use `for in` with arrays.

Comment: This is for communication purpose. I need to translate the hexstring incoming message, create the response message, send the response message back as hexstring too. So I need String.fromCharCode and quite confuse why it is called super strange.
Thanks for the tips for {for in} ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code seems to be working for me if I decode it again.
Careful though with for() loops over objects in Javacript. That also iterates over the properties of an object.

```
var str = [0x6A, 0xE8, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xD9, 0xDC, 0x0A, 0x09];
byte = '';
for (var i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
    byte += String.fromCharCode( parseInt(str[i], 16).toString(16) );
}

var hexarrayout = [];
for (var i=0; i<byte.length; i++) {
    hexarrayout.push(byte.charCodeAt(i).toString(16));
}

alert(hexarrayout);
```

​
Example on http://jsfiddle.net/ycG4n/

Your problem looks very much like a utf8<=>iso-.../ascii/etc conversion problem when sending to your receiver, where some of your 1byte string chars are converted into 2byte chars. Due to the partial backwards compatibility of UTF-8, some of your hex values would be kept 1byte.

Comment: There's no objects in the code the OP posted. And you need to be careful using normal `for` loops with actual objects. `for in` loops are perfectly fine with objects. Normal `for` loops are perfectly fine with arrays. But your solution uses the right `for` loop for this

Comment: so how I can manage this backward compability since have no problems between python and php script?

Answer (score 2):

Even though you're writing `0x6A` in your code, JavaScript automatically understands it as its value, 106. It is already a number, so `parseInt()` won't do anything to it and can be removed.

You might just want to do this:

```
var str = [0x6A,0xE8...];
var byte = String.fromCharCode.apply(null,str);
```

Comment: sometimes it read as "0x6A" (string). I just want to make sure it parsed as a hexstring